# understanding complex dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am entirely new to python and has been working on something which requires to go through some complex dictionary that looks something like this.

```
var_data:
{
     'pvc' : {
         'files' : ['logs1.txt', 'logs2.txt']
         'version' : 'v192.2'
     },
     'mci' : {
         'files' : ['ld33r3.txt', 'rkkk3k3.txt']
         'version' : 'v39.2'
     },
     'dac' : {
         'files' : ['33.txt', 'logfile3.txt']
         'version' : 'v32.2'
     }
}
```

I am beating my head around to understand how this reference is.
Basically my code should be able to have a if condition that will look at this data and do specific conditinal statements for the "files" depending on the value above it..
e.g
'dac' : {

Really appreciate any guidance in this...

cheers
Kabeer

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the `do specific conditinal statements for the "files" depending on the value above it.. e.g 'dac' : {` part?

Do you want to have different `if-elif-else`s if the outermost keys (eg., `dac`), are different?

Comment: Please try a tutorial first?

Comment: The condition is clear... What i am struggling with is how to extract these values from this dictionary.. e.g if I am able see the 'pvc' : { part then I should be able to get the corresponding 'files' : ['logs1.txt', 'logs2.txt']

Comment: the code that i put on the question is the value that i get in my code as a dictionary. But now I have to analyze these files based what type of files it is. The type of the file is determined by the values "mci", "dac" , "pvc" etc it can be more... The part that i am struggling is understanding how to extract the filetype and the number of files from this dictionary

Comment: The code you have posted is not of a dictionary, it looks like a string. Please post the _exact input_ you are working with.

Answer (score 1):

> I am beating my head around to understand how this reference is.

You have a dictionary that contains 3 dictionaries that each contain a list of strings and a single string.

> my code should be able to have a if condition that will look at this data and do specific conditinal statements for the "files" depending on the value above it.. e.g 'dac'

You can loop over it:

```
for k, v in var_data.iteritems():
  if k == 'pvc':
    # do stuff. Your files list is in v['files']
  elif k == 'mci':
    # do other stuff
  elif k == 'dac':
    # do other stuff
```

Comment: @KabeerNoorudeen I literally said how you can do that in the comments in the code block

Comment: @KabeerNoorudeen as it is right now, var_data is not a valid Python dictionary have you tested this?

Comment: @JoeR it's not a big deal I think. He said the dict *looks something like this*

Comment: @Tim appreciate you helping me out... the code that i put on the question is the value that i get in my code as a dictionary. But now I have to analyze these files based what type of files it is. The type of the file is determined by the values "mci", "dac" , "pvc" etc it can be more... The part that i am struggling is understanding how to extract the filetype and the number of files from this dictionary...

Comment: @KabeerNoorudeen for example if you want to extract 'mci' and the number of files that belong to it you can do `var_data['mci']` to get the entire mci dictionary, and `len(var_data['mci']['files'])` to get the number of files

Comment: Thanks for your help Tim. I think this would work for me.. i am doing some testing.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, unless you update your question with what I wrote in my comment, I think this is what you want ? :-

```
def process_files(files):
"""
Do some processing on a list of files,
specified by their names
"""

    for file_name in files:
        with open(file_name, 'r+') as file:  # Will work if script in same dir as the files. Else, make the absolute path to file using file_name, and put that instead of just file_name
            file_content = file.read()
            # Do whatever else.
            # Perhaps, read the documentation examples
            # first, get a feeling, then come back


for key in var_data:  # For each key in your dict, (iteration happening here)
    if key == 'pvc':
        # do something on var_data[key]
        files = var_data[key]['files']  # Get your list ['file1.txt', ..]
        process_files(files)   # process this list of files in some func.
    elif key == 'mci':
        # do something else
    elif key == 'dac':
        # and so on.
```

Also, your dictionary is not well constructed. It's missing commas at the end of the `files` keys' values. And `var_data:` is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're asking how to pull key-value pairs from a dictionary.  iteritems() is probably the most syntactically compact way.  Here's an example:

```
var_data = {
    'pvc': {
        'files': ['logs1.txt', 'logs2.txt'],
        'version': 'v192.2'
    },
    'mci': {
        'files': ['ld33r3.txt', 'rkkk3k3.txt'],
        'version': 'v39.2'
    },
    'dac': {
        'files': ['33.txt', 'logfile3.txt'],
        'version': 'v32.2'
    }
}

for filetype, data in var_data.iteritems():
    for filename in data['files']:
        print 'Processing {} as type {}'.format(filename, filetype)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the dictionary have some invalid syntax so there is nothing you can do with this as is, because this is not a valid Python dictionary.

For example *I will just take the fist part* but it's the same problem throughout the dictionary.

This is what you have:

```
var_data : {'pvc' : {'files' : ['logs1.txt', 'logs2.txt'] 'version' : 'v192.2'}
```

If you run this you will get an `invalid syntax` error. This is how you should fix that *please see* `},` after `['logs1.txt', 'logs2.txt']` and `=` after `var_data` instead of `:` you have to fix this same problem in the entire dictionary, *please see corrected line below:*

```
var_data = {'pvc' : {'files' : ['logs1.txt', 'logs2.txt']}, 'version' : 'v192.2'}
```

Now, after you fix this, if you want to `print` for example `var_data['pvc']` you will get this output:`{'files': ['logs1.txt', 'logs2.txt']}`. If you want to see all the `keys` of your dictionary, you can `print` the `keys` like this:

```
print var_data.keys() #Python 2
print (var_data.keys()) #Python 3
```

The output will be:

```
['pvc', 'version', 'mci', 'dac']
```

As far as the `if` statements, I am not sure what you wan to do exactly but now at least you can use the `if` statements.

If you want to explain exactly what you need to do with the if statements, I will update my answer accordingly.